# Form_tag remote in Rails 3 in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

To become member, A user can use a button to create a membership on the community page. This is made on a partial that create a new "membership"
the memberships_controller :

```
 @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
 @community.memberships.create(:user => current_user, :role => 1)
```

in The view :

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => community_memberships_path(@community) do %>
   <%= submit_tag 'Join' %>
<% end %>
```

**After upgrading to Rails 3, that doesn't work anymore !**

I tried this :

```
<% form_tag( {:url => community_memberships_path(@community)}, :remote => true) do %>
```

and this :

```
<% form_tag :url => {:controller => '/memberships/new', :action => :create,:community_id => @community }, :remote => true do %>
```

But no chance.. and have this error

> No route matches "/communities/2

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is the first argument, options are secondary.

```
<% form_tag(community_memberships_path(@community), :remote => true) do %>
   ...
```

As for your `No route matches` exception, check you have translated you routes to the Rails 3 syntax correctly.